# pdf font not being used in PDF form field

Tags: pdf, acrobat, fdf

So I'm using an FDF to auto populate a PDFs form fields. Here's the FDF:

```
%FDF-1.2
1 0 obj
<<
/FDF << /Fields [
<< /T (bar1) /V (*FAX7033102534*)>>

 ] /F (http://domain.tld/demo.pdf) /ID [ <138ff91476c2ae9c9f192e15ac50d7bf>
] >>
>>
endobj
trailer
<<
/Root 1 0 R

>>
%%EOF
```

The `bar1` form field uses a barcode font - [IDAutomationHC39M](http://www.dafont.com/idautomationhc39m.font).

The problem is...  when I view the PDF I'm not seeing the `bar1` field as a barcode using the IDAutomationHC39M font. If I click in the `bar1` field, as though to edit it, the barcode font appears but if I click outside of the `bar1` field the barcode magically reverts to the non-barcode font.

Here's the PDF (with the FDF already applied):

http://www.frostjedi.com/terra/demo.pdf

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the correct symbol appear when you manually enter data?

Comment: Yes. I'm almost wondering if it's because I have the custom font on my local system but maybe it's not being embedded in the PDF. And if it's not being embedded in the PDF then why isn't it?

Comment: Unless the font has embedding restrictions, it should be automatically embedded when you set it for a form field in Acrobat.

Comment: comment deleted because it was wrong.